# Transaction Issue with Hibernate and ehCache configuration

Tags: hibernate, ehcache, jta

In my hibernate mapping i have the cache usage as read-only

```
<class name="cdot.ctms.layer.services.dispatch.data.DispatchMapDTO"
        table="DISPATCH_MAP" mutable="false" optimistic-lock="version">
        <cache usage="read-only"/>
```

In my ehCache.xml I have the default cache settings as

```
<defaultCache
            maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="120"
            timeToLiveSeconds="120"
            diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
            maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000"
            diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
            transactionalMode="xa_strict">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    </defaultCache>
```

When my object picks up the default cache it runs into transaction rolled back issue.

If i add a cache explicitly for the object i am referring to, i do not run into any issues.

```
<cache 
        name="cdot.ctms.layer.services.dispatch.data.DispatchMapDTO" 
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="100" 
        eternal="false"
        timeToLiveSeconds="300">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>
```

We have a lot of DTO's which use the default cache in our application. Do i have to define cache's like above in my ehCache.xml for each object? Did not find any related documentation in hibernate manual around it

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-cache-readonly

Can someone explain what is wrong with my configuration and what are the best practices for the above problem.

2015-02-24 10:05:27,390 ERROR (http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-6) [cdot.ctms.layer.web.fire.spring.AtmosphereHandlerExceptionResolver] ExceptionResolver error is: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction marked for rollback
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction marked for rollback
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1024)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.jencks.GeronimoPlatformTransactionManager.commit(GeronimoPlatformTransactionManager.java:76)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.getDispatchMaps(Unknown Source)
    at cdot.ctms.layer.delegate.controllers.DispatchController.getDispatchMaps(DispatchController.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at cdot.ctms.layer.delegate.facade.AnnotationDelegateController.executeInternal(AnnotationDelegateController.java:287)
    at cdot.ctms.layer.delegate.facade.AnnotationDelegateController.processAction(AnnotationDelegateController.java:232)
    at cdot.ctms.layer.web.controller.BaseWebController.processAction(BaseWebController.java:94)
    at cdot.ctms.layer.web.dispatch.controller.DispatchController.findDispatchMapsUnderSection(DispatchController.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.atmosphere.util.AtmosphereFilterChain.doFilter(AtmosphereFilterChain.java:135)
    at org.atmosphere.util.AtmosphereFilterChain.invokeFilterChain(AtmosphereFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor$FilterChainServletWrapper.service(ReflectorServletProcessor.java:317)
    at org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor.onRequest(ReflectorServletProcessor.java:160)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:205)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:104)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.service(Servlet30CometSupport.java:66)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2079)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doPost(AtmosphereServlet.java:211)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doGet(AtmosphereServlet.java:197)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at cdot.web.filter.BaseWebRequestFilter.doFilter(BaseWebRequestFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at cdot.web.filter.BaseWebRequestFilter.doFilter(BaseWebRequestFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction marked for rollback
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.rollbackResourcesDuringCommit(TransactionImpl.java:670)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:322)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:252)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1021)
    ... 105 more

Answer (score 0):

You have differences between the default cache config and the specific one. Among them is the `timeToLiveSeconds`.

What happens if you bump the default cache one to `300` also?

Comment: Tried that before, did not help.

Comment: Then I recommend bumping the log level of your transaction manager to figure out the root cause of the rollback.